# Bash Scripting and bc

Tags: bash, scripting, sh, bc

I'm trying to write a bash script and I needed to do some floating point math.  Basically I want to do something like this:

```
NUM=$(echo "scale=25;$1/10" | bc)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
echo bad
fi
```

The problem I'm running into is $? tends to hold the output from the echo program and not the bc call.  Is there a way I save the output from the bc program into a variable?

EDIT:

Thanks for the quick replies.  Here's another way of looking at the problem.  Say I modified the script a little bit so it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
NUM=$(echo "scale=25;$1/10" | bc)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
echo bad
exit
fi
echo "$NUM"
```

When the user inputs a normal floating point value, it works fine:

```
bash script.sh 1.0
```

output:

```
.1000000000000000000000000
```

However, when the user enters an incorrect value, the script can't recover:

```
bash script.sh 1.0a
```

output:

```
(standard_in) 1: parse error
```

What I'm trying to do is get it to exit gracefully.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong. $NUM is supposed to hold your `bc` command results

see:

```
NUM=$(echo "scale=25;$1/10" | bc)
echo "\$? is $?"
echo "NUM is $NUM"
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh 10
$? is 0
NUM is 1.0000000000000000000000000
```

another way is to use awk

```
NUM=$(awk -vinput="$1" 'BEGIN{printf "%.25f", input/10 }')
echo "\$? is $?"
echo "NUM is $NUM"
```

The other way, is to do the check of "$1" before you pass to `bc`. eg

```
shopt -s extglob
input="$1"
case "$input" in
 +([0-9.]))
     IFS="."; set -- $input
     if [ $# -ne 2 ];then
        echo "bad decimal"
     else
        NUM=$(echo "scale=25;$1/10" | bc  )
        echo "$NUM"
     fi
esac
```

you don't have to check for `$?` from `bc` anymore

Comment: Remember that the successful echo of 'NUM is $NUM' will have overwritten the value in $? from the '$(echo ... | bc)' command.

Comment: I clarified my post above.  Thanks for the tip on awk.  If I can't get bc to work, I'll have to check it out.

Comment: another way, is to sanitize your input $1 to be a decimal or number before passing to `bc`. see my edit.

Comment: That's a cleaver check, but is there any way to make sure there's only one '.' character present?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For GNU `bc`, an error similar to "(standard_in) 1: syntax error" will be output on stderr. You can capture this in your variable and check for it.

```
#!/bin/bash
NUM=$(echo "scale=25;$1/10" | bc 2>&1)
if [[ $NUM =~ error || $? -ne 0 ]]
then
    echo bad
    exit
fi
echo "$NUM"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you after the result of calculation from bc (which you store in NUM) or the status return from the system call?

As I said you have the result of calculation in `$NUM`:

```
#bctest.sh
NUM=$(echo "scale=25;$1/10" | bc)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
echo bad
fi

echo "result: ", $NUM
```

Test:

```
bash ./bctest.sh 15
result: , 1.5000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: I was trying to get the status return from the system call.  Sorry, I should have been more explicit.