# variable error in bash when doing calculation

Tags: bash, pipe, syntax-error, variable-assignment, command-substitution

I assigned output of piping into a variable, but when I try to use the variable to do math, it won't allow me:

```
%%bash
cd /data/ref/
grep -v ">" EN | wc -c > ref
cat ref
cd /example/
grep -v ">" SR | wc -l > sample
cat sample

echo $((x= cat sample, y= cat ref, u=x/y, z=u*100))
```

I get this error:

```
41858
38986
bash: line 7: x= cat sample, y= cat ref, u=x/y, z=u*100: syntax error in expression (error token is "sample, y= cat ref, u=x/y, z=u*100"
```

Comment: @user432797 : The word _cat_ is not a number, nor a variable. Even if were a variable, the word _sample_ afterwards does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You received that error because you passed an invalid arithmetic expression into a bash [arithetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html). Only an arithmetic expression is allowed for this place. What you try to do seems like this:

```sh
ref="$(grep -v ">" /data/ref/EN | wc -c)"
sample="$(grep -v ">" /example/SR | wc -l)"

# this is only integer division
#u=$(( sample / ref ))
#z=$(( 100 * u ))

# to do math calculations, you can use bc
u=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $sample/$ref")
z=$(bc <<< "scale=2; 100*$u")

printf "%d, %d, %.2f, %.2f\n" "$ref" "$sample" "$u" "$z"
```

so hopefully you get an output like this:

```
41858, 38986, 0.93, 93.00
```

Notes:

- There is no need to `cd` before executing a `grep`, it accepts the full path with the target filename as an argument. So without changing directory, you can `grep` various locations.
- In order to save the output of your command (which is only a number) you don't need to save it in a file and `cat` the file. Just use the syntax `var=$( )` and `var` will be assigned the output of this [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution).
- Have in mind that `/` will result to 0 for the division `38986/41858` because it's the integer division. If you want to do math calculations with decimals, you can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331936/bash-scripting-and-bc) for how to do them using `bc`.
- To print anything, use the shell builtin [`printf`](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf). Here the last two numbers are formatted with 2 decimal points.

Comment: That was helpful @thanasisp, I was reading this but I couldn't see how to apply it to my question https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/math-arithmetic-calculation/ but your answer covered a lot. Now I have to learn printf, is there anything easier than printf to print the output directly?

Comment: yes, use `echo "$ref" "$sample" "$u" "$z"` Have in mind that it prints with 2 decimal points because we passed scale=2 to bc, so we got this result. With `printf` you can interpolate text, do a lot of things, for printing just a variable echo is ok.